# I NEED TO FIND LETTER IN ITEMS LIST

Tags: list

list_name = ['shlomi', 'nir', 'moshe', 'david', 'itzik', 'yoda', 'noa', 'hila', 'lae', 'nava']

if x in list_name contain 'i' 
print 'this name contain i in it':
    else:
        print x 'this name does not contain i in it'

Comment: 1. Read about [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). 2. Tag a language. 3. Ask a question. (For more info go to the [help] and read [ask].)

Answer (score 0):

list_name = ['shlomi', 'nir', 'moshe', 'david', 'itzik', 'yoda', 'noa', 'hila', 'lae', 'nava']

for item in list_name:
    if (item.find('i')) != -1:
        print ('Found at ', item)